# Slope filtration vs Hodge filtration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, with $X_0$ its reduction mod $p$. Assume that $X_0$ is ordinary.

For any lift $X'$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $X_0$, there is a canonical isomorphism
$$H^i_\text{cris}(X_0 / \mathbb{Z}_p) \cong H^i_\text{dR}(X'/\mathbb{Z}_p)$$

The left side of this isomorphism has a slope filtration, while the right side has a Hodge filtration, but I don't think this isomorphism is filtered in general.

Is there an example of $X_0$ as above such that no $X'$ can be chosen to make the isomorphism above filtered?

Comment: What if $X_0$ is a supersingular elliptic curve?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I have amended the question.

Comment: Just a comment, but the general result is that the Hodge Filtration is **opposed** to the filtration by increasing slopes (a result of Hyodo, explained by Illusie in the Bourbaki seminar). As the *usual* slope filtration (or filtration by decreasing slopes) is also opposed to the filtration by increasing slopes, both are opposed to the same filtration. They are usually distinct (but I don't know the answer to your question).